# What is the global problem in the two-level additive Schwarz?

Tags: finite-element, domain-decomposition

The two-level additive Schwarz method (additive Schwarz with a coarse space correction) is often written like this:
$$
\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=0}^N \mathbf{R}_i^T \mathbf{A}^{-1}_i\mathbf{R}_i\mathbf{w}
$$

where the term $i=0$ is said to be the coarse space correction. $\mathbf{A}_0$ is the solver for a global coarse grid problem, $\mathbf{R}_0$ and $\mathbf{R}_0^T$ the restriction and interpolation operators, respectively.

My question is, how to construct $\mathbf{A}_0$? Which problem does it correspond to? I get the idea of creating a coarse mesh, in fact, I am already using a coarse mesh to make an initial guess for what the solution of the global problem should be. But the two-level additive Schwarz method solves a coarse problem in each iteration and I don't understand what problem this is supposed to be. I assume we are not solving the same coarse grid problem over and over, something must change in between the iterations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Continuous finite elements**

Typically, if $A$ is your finite element discretization on the finest mesh, $A_i = R_i * A * R_i^T$.  So, for $i=0$, $A_0$ corresponds to the finite element discretization of your problem on the coarsest mesh.

If $R_0$ and $R_0^T$ are algebraically defined, you can use the "Galerkin" triple product to form $A_0=R_0 * A * R_0^T$.  This is what is done in algebraic multigrid.  If $R_0$ and $R_0^T$ have geometric meaning, $A_0$ can be constructed by simply assembling your finite element problem on the coarsest mesh.

Within the two-level additive Schwarz iteration, usually the matrices $A$ and $A_0$ remain fixed.  If you are trying to solve $Ax=b$, and $x_j$ is your previous guess to the problem, then the $j+1$ iteration of the two-level additive Schwarz method looks like

$$x_{j+1} = x_j + \sum_{i=0}^N R_i^T A_i^{-1}R_i  (b-Ax_j).$$

In other words, the matrices $A_0$ and $A_i$ do not depend on $j$.  [Chapter 4 in this free book](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01100932/file/bookddm.pdf) explains why a coarse space is useful.

**Nonlinear problems**

For Nonlinear problems that are resolved with an outer Newton or Picard iteration, the matrices $A$ and $A_0$ are dependent on the outer iteration.

**Spectral elements**

In the case of spectral elements, many authors select $A_0$ so that it corresponds to a finite element problem on the coarsest mesh with a smaller polynomial order (for example look at [Fischer et al](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~fischer/pubhtml/ima2000.pdf) and [Pasquetti et al](http://www.courant.nyu.edu/dd16/proceedings/pavarino_contributed.pdf)).

**Discontinuous Galkerin methods**

It has been shown that the selection of coarse spaces for discontinuous Galkerkin methods can be a little more sensitive.  Further details can be seen in the following references [Olson et al](https://www.cims.nyu.edu/dd16/proceedings/olson_contrib.pdf), [Dobrev et al](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/nla.504/abstract), [Antonietti](http://www1.mate.polimi.it/~antonietti/DOWNLOAD/Antonietti_PhDthesis.pdf), and [Collins](http://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4887&context=utk_graddiss).